# Find $b$ when $(2+\sqrt{3})^n=5042+b\sqrt{3}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find $b$ when $(2+\sqrt{3})^n=5042+b\sqrt{3}$

I saw that $n$ cannot be bigger than $11$ because then the rational part is going to be bigger than $5024$. But I don't know how to find the $n$ exactly and how to find out $b$ then. Any hints?

**Note**: $b$ and $n$ are integers.

Comment: Trying and failing is probably the way to go, since the exponent doesn't get too high anyway. Do you know the binomial theorem?

Comment: Yes of course I know that but it didn't help me.It be's too long.

Comment: Try to find $(a_n)_n$ and $(b_n)_n$ such as $(2+/sqrt{3})^n=a_n+b_n /sqrt{3}$. I am not sure of this but it could work.

Comment: I know but the problem is finding them.

Comment: Use newton $(1+\sqrt{3}/2)^n=...$ separate odd and even. Or use induction finding $a_{n+1}$ and $b_{n+1}$  expressed with $a_n$ and $b_n$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that $2+\sqrt{3}$ is a root of $x^2-4x+1$. Therefore the sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ defined by
$$(2+\sqrt{3})^n=a_n+b_n\sqrt{3}$$
will both satisfy
$$a_n=4a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}\qquad \qquad b_n=4b_{n-1}-b_{n-2}$$
with initial values, of course, given by
$$\begin{align*}
(2+\sqrt{3})^0=1+0\sqrt{3}&\; \implies \; a_0=1,\quad b_0=0\\
(2+\sqrt{3})^1=2+1\sqrt{3}&\; \implies \; a_1=2,\quad b_1=1
\end{align*}$$
You're told that
$$(2+\sqrt{3})^n=a_n+b_n\sqrt{3}=5042+b\sqrt{3}$$
for some $n$, and asked to find $b$. To do this, you just need to find the value of $n$ for which $a_n=5042$, and then compute the corresponding value of $b_n$.

Given the recurrences and initial values, you can of course now use brute force on the sequence $a_n$, computing higher and higher values 
$$a_0 = 1,\qquad a_1 = 2,\qquad a_2=7,\qquad a_3=26,\qquad a_4=97,\qquad \ldots$$
until you find the $n$ that gives you $5042$, at which point you would then compute $b_n$ for that $n$, and be done.

---

However, it may be useful to have an alternative approach, e.g. if you were told to find the value of $n$ for which $$a_n=19785515999613069781581367687$$
you may prefer to skip the tedious calculations.

Note that the other root of $x^2-4x+1$ is $2-\sqrt{3}$, so both $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ will satisfy
$$\begin{align*}
a_n&=A_0(2+\sqrt{3})^n+A_1(2-\sqrt{3})^n\\
b_n&=B_0(2+\sqrt{3})^n+B_1(2-\sqrt{3})^n
\end{align*}$$
for some numbers $A_0,A_1,B_0,B_1$, which you can deduce using the initial values of $a_0,a_1,b_0,b_1$.

Note that $|2-\sqrt{3}|<1$ so the contribution from that term to the overall value of $a_n$ becomes negligible for large $n$. Therefore $a_n\approx A_0(2+\sqrt{3})^n$ for large $n$, so 
$$n\approx\log_{2+\sqrt{3}}(a_n/A_0)=\frac{\log(a_n)-\log(A_0)}{\log(2+\sqrt{3})}$$
You can then plug in and check the value of $a_n$ for integers close to this value to find the exact $n$.

Comment: so what is the answer?

Comment: @TahaAkbari: I'm giving you a hint - try to work out the details yourself.

Comment: Very nice -- +1

Comment: could you please give the answer.

Comment: @TahaAkbari: What have you tried already? Which specific part of my post are you having trouble with? It'll be better practice for you to do the calculation yourself.

Comment: I think n is ging to be $7$ yes?

Comment: @TahaAkbari: That's right - so now you just have to find $b_7$.

Comment: Since this is an accepted answer, I note  a typo.  5042 not 5024.  I would edit but rep <2k, so to avoid havig to go thru peer review I ask the answerer to do so.

Comment: @OscarLanzi: Thanks for catching that, I've corrected now.

Answer (score 5):

First note that

$(2+\sqrt{3})^n = a+b\sqrt{3}$

with $a,b$ both positive whole  for any positive whole number $n$. There is also a conjugate relation

$(2-\sqrt{3})^n = a-b\sqrt{3}$

and then we have the product of these two relations

$1 = a^2-3b^2$

For any positive whole number $n$ the product relation implies that $b$ is the largest whole number less than $a/\sqrt{3}$.  So punch that quotient into your calculator with the given value of $a$ and read off the whole-number part.

Comment: How did you know there is a conjugate? which sentence\theorem do you use?

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer. +1

Comment: This is a good answer but there is a problem how will you divide by the squeeze root of 3?If you want to calculate the squeeze root of 3 it will be hard to calculate and if you don't calculate so exactly you will catch a wrong number for example if I put 1.73 for the square root of 3 I will get the number 2994.

Comment: ??? @taha you cannot use a calculator?  I do not see this in the problem statement.

Comment: by a calculator you won't get an exact answer either.because maybe the answer is a bit smaller than a natural number but if you divide by a calculator you will get a bit more than that number.

Comment: "...and read off the whole-number part".